# Android Asynchronous Task class

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

currently i am working on a project with tab activity where each tab call web service to fetch data from server and show them in list view. Now i want to manage this in a way that when my app starts every tabs data will be fetched from the server and user can see them without making the web service call on every tab change listener. So is there any way to fetch all the values from web in a single service call and share those service call return objects in every activity.

Comment: why don't you try it yourself and tell us?

Answer (score 0):

In a single service call depends what the service returns, if it does not return everything you need then of course not.
But you can get all the data you need in one AsyncTask execution for sure, whether it takes one or more calls depends on the service.
Once you have the data you just need to make it accessible to all your activities which shouldn't be that hard.

Now get busy coding and return if you run into some problems that you cannot seem to solve by yourself and that you cannot find the solution for.

Good luck.